# Validate cell data before importing to database in code igniter using phpExcel

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

I'm having a hard time figuring this problem out.

I just started playing around with phpExcel library. I'm trying to build a function that will allow users to import their data to the database. I'm using Code Igniter's batch insert function to send the data to the database. I got it to work, but I needed to set some rules on some of the cells within the range. For instance, some cells must not be empty, others should be numeric, etc. That's where I'm stuck. 
This is what I have done so far:

```
public function import_students_action() {
            //config for file uploads
            $config['upload_path']          = './assets/uploads/imports/students'; //path to save the files
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'xls|xlsx';  //extensions which are allowed
            $config['max_size']             = 1024 * 2; //image size cannot exceed 2MB
            $config['file_ext_tolower']     = TRUE; //force file extension to lower case
            $config['remove_spaces']        = TRUE; //replace space in file names with underscores to avoid break
            $config['detect_mime']          = TRUE; //detect type of file to avoid code injection
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( $_FILES['excel_file']['name'] == "" ) { //file is not selected
                $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg_error', "No file selected!");
                $this->import_students(); //reload page

            } elseif ( ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('excel_file')) && ($_FILES['excel_file']['name'] != "") ) {     
                //upload does not happen when file is selected
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                $this->import_students($error); //reload page with upload errors

            } else { //file is selected, upload happens, everyone is happy

                $path = $_FILES["excel_file"]["tmp_name"];
                $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

                $last_name = "";
                $first_name = "";
                $class = "";
                $highestRow = "";

                foreach ($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
                    $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); //last row with data
                    $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); //last column with data

                    //start loop from 2nd row. Row 1 is title row
                    for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++) {
                        $last_name = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue();
                        $first_name = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue();
                        $class = $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue();
                        $data[] = array(
                            'school_id'  => school_id,
                            'last_name'  => $last_name,
                            'first_name'   => $first_name,
                            'class'    => $class,
                        );
                    }
                }

                //validation rules
                if  ($last_name == NULL || $first_name == NULL || $class == NULL) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg_error', 'Import failed! Ensure all required fields are filled properly.');
                } else {
                    $this->data_import_model->import_students($data);
                    $highestRow = $highestRow - 1; //total rows with content - 1 (title row)
                    $students = ($highestRow == 1) ? 'student' : 'students';
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg', "{$highestRow} {$students} imported successfully.");
                }
                redirect('data_import/import_students');
            } 
        }
```

With the above code, the insert command executes even if a required cell is empty. I need it to throw error if a required cell is empty. If I can get it right, I can apply other rules. Also, I will like to know how to apply the rules and error messages as an array.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post a sample of the excel file you are dealing with,

Answer (score 0):

you need to make the code stop execution or to redirect to the previous page,
I also used method `empty` as it is more convenient to detect empty and null values.
  check the below code:

```
 public function import_students_action() {
                //config for file uploads
                $config['upload_path']          = './assets/uploads/imports/students'; //path to save the files
                $config['allowed_types']        = 'xls|xlsx';  //extensions which are allowed
                $config['max_size']             = 1024 * 2; //image size cannot exceed 2MB
                $config['file_ext_tolower']     = TRUE; //force file extension to lower case
                $config['remove_spaces']        = TRUE; //replace space in file names with underscores to avoid break
                $config['detect_mime']          = TRUE; //detect type of file to avoid code injection
                $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                if ( $_FILES['excel_file']['name'] == "" ) { //file is not selected
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg_error', "No file selected!");
                    $this->import_students(); //reload page

                } elseif ( ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('excel_file')) && ($_FILES['excel_file']['name'] != "") ) {     
                    //upload does not happen when file is selected
                    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                    $this->import_students($error); //reload page with upload errors

                } else { //file is selected, upload happens, everyone is happy

                    $path = $_FILES["excel_file"]["tmp_name"];
                    $object = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($path);

                    $last_name = "";
                    $first_name = "";
                    $class = "";
                    $highestRow = "";

                    foreach ($object->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
                        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); //last row with data
                        $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); //last column with data

                        //start loop from 2nd row. Row 1 is title column
                        for ($row=2; $row<=$highestRow; $row++) {
                            $last_name = trim($worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(0, $row)->getValue());
                            $first_name = trim($worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getValue());
                            $class = trim($worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getValue());
                            $data[] = array(
                                'school_id'  => school_id,
                                'last_name'  => $last_name,
                                'first_name'   => $first_name,
                                'class'    => $class,
                            );
                        }
                    }

                    //validation rules
                    if  (empty($last_name) || empty($first_name) || empty($class) ) {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg_error', 'Import failed! Ensure all required fields are filled properly.');
redirect('data_import/error');
exit;
                    } else {
                        $this->data_import_model->import_students($data);
                        $highestRow = $highestRow - 1; //total rows with content - 1 (title row)
                        $students = ($highestRow == 1) ? 'student' : 'students';
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('status_msg', "{$highestRow} {$students} imported successfully.");
                    }
                    redirect('data_import/import_students');
                } 
            }
```

Comment: I'm afraid this didn't work @Ray A. The insertion still happened

Comment: I edited the code, I added trim to the first_name, last_name and class, test it

Comment: Just tested it, it still inserts.